# How to svn merge this branch to trunk?

Tags: svn, svn-merge-reintegrate

I am trying to clean up this old svn repository. The project repo is very simple:

- `/trunk/` used to be the main branch, it has been untouched since rev 531.
- `/branches/Version2` is the new main branch, at rev 1300. It's essentially the master branch now; everyone works from this branch. It is merged up-to-date with `trunk`.

We want to reintegrate `Version2` back to `trunk`.

When I do:

```
svn merge --reintegrate ..\branches\Version2
```

I keep having problems. Either SVN crashes, or it errors with "truncated html response" after merging only a couple of the thousands of files.

Honestly, this is such a simple merge (literally naively replacing `trunk` with `Version2`), is there some other way to do this that works around the failing merge? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Short of a dump-reload cycle, why can't you simply `svn delete trunk` and then `svn move branches/Version2 trunk`?

Comment: Except easy @SameerSingh idea, you can 1. Export `Version2` HEAD into unversioned tree 2. **Totally replace** Working Copy of trunk with results of export from step 1 (don't touch only .svn dir) 3. Commit result of replacement - you'll lost intermediate history /in trunk only/

Comment: That feels hacky @LazyBadger haha :)

Comment: Actually Sameer's method seems totally reasonable. We will do this. In the meantime I'm pushing to migrate to git :) Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of a dump-reload cycle, why can't you simply `svn delete trunk` and then `svn move branches/Version2 trunk`?

Also, @LazyBadger's comment above seems to be a perfectly valid alternative, but if you have files in `trunk` that were `svn delete`d in the `Version2` branch, you'd still have these present after the manual sync he suggested. Even if you manually delete (i.e Windows / Linux / Mac delete) everything in `trunk` first, then manually sync with the `Version2` branch, you'd still have to remember to "mark as deleted" the files that SVN will now report as missing.

For files `svn add`ed in `Version2`, post-manual-sync to `trunk`, SVN will report them as being non-versioned, and you'd have to remember to `svn add` them.

There have been times where I was forced to do this sort of thing, and it isn't pretty.